# Mysql: create enriched view?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a view that is, sadly, quite slow in retrieving data.

Now I think I read about enriched views. What is the technical term for that?

I read as well that mysql does not support that. What is the most painless way, to get that feature for mysql or, well, to the most similar DB like mysql?

asanatt_task

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `asanatt_task` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tid` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `project` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `play_date` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `worked_time` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `estimated_time` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `userid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `userid` (`userid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1073 ;
```

some random examples:

```
INSERT INTO `asanatt_task` (`id`, `tid`, `project`, `name`, `username`, `play_date`, `worked_time`, `estimated_time`, `created_on`, `userid`) VALUES
(147, '41968880601380', '.', 'Work on Asana  ', 'a@bl.com', '2015-07-20', '', '', '2015-08-06 21:22:39', 42006768531733),
(148, '41968880601376', '.', 'Play with Asana       ', 'a@bl.com', '2015-07-20', '', '', '2015-08-06 21:22:39', 42006768531733),
(149, '41968880601361', '.', 'fix time tracker  ', 'a@bl.com', '2015-07-20', '', '', '2015-08-06 21:22:39', 42006768531733),
(150, '44504385830921', '.', 'Consider updating your project status', 'a@baaal.com', '2015-08-06', '', '', '2015-08-06 22:56:34', 0),
(151, '36230536420499', '.', 'Software ', 'a@baaal.com', '2015-06-01', '', '', '2015-08-06 22:56:34', 0);
```

my asanatt_worktime table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `asanatt_worktime` (
  `tid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `userid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `work_begin` datetime NOT NULL,
  `work_end` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tid`,`userid`,`work_begin`),
  KEY `work_end` (`work_end`),
  KEY `work_begin` (`work_begin`),
  KEY `userid` (`userid`),
  KEY `tid` (`tid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

some random examples

```
INSERT INTO `asanatt_worktime` (`tid`, `userid`, `work_begin`, `work_end`) VALUES
(44504385830921, 13084161448998, '2015-08-06 15:07:15', '2015-08-06 15:08:24');
```

my slightly complex view:

```
CREATE algorithm=undefined definer=`root`@`localhost` SQL security definer view `asanatt_report_workbydate`
AS 
  SELECT    `t`.`project`                                                                AS `projectname`,
            `t`.`name`                                                                   AS `taskname`,
            `w`.`tid`                                                                    AS `tid`,
            `t`.`username`                                                               AS `username`,
            `w`.`userid`                                                                 AS `userid`,
            cast(`w`.`work_begin` AS date)                                               AS `selected_date`,
            round(sum((timestampdiff(second,`w`.`work_begin`,`w`.`work_end`) / 3600)),3) AS `worked_hours`
  FROM      (`asanatt_worktime` `w` 
  LEFT JOIN `asanatt_task` `t` 
  ON       ((( 
                                          `w`.`userid` = `t`.`userid`) 
                      AND       ( 
                                          `t`.`tid` = `w`.`tid`)))) 
  GROUP BY  `w`.`userid`, 
            `w`.`tid`, 
            `w`.`work_begin` 
  ORDER BY  cast(`w`.`work_begin` AS date) DESC;
```

Comment: show your code and your related schema ..

Comment: @scaisEdge i updated the question. The basic question remains though, is it possible to create enriched views or how to do something like that

Comment: note: this is slow, if used to retrieve, the hours worked from the view, of 100 tasks, on 4 days. So, 400 entries

Comment: what suggest by @koby is right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/!\ you are joining `t.tid = w.tid` according to your table definition:
one column is `bigint(20) not null` with an `index`,
the other one is `varchar(200) null` `without index`

Can you consider changing datatypes to bigint for both and add an index on the table `asanatt_task` ?

Comment: btw what is the term for "enriched view" ? does that exist for postgresql?